# Plot multiple x,y co-ordinates using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm attempting to plot multiple x,y co-ordinates on a graph using ggplot2.

Here is similar graph I'm attempting to create :

[image]

Here is code I'm trying with points (2,1) (2,2) (2,3):

```
x = c(2,2,2)
y = c(1,2,3)
df = data.frame(x , y)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x="x", y="y")) +
    geom_point(shape=1)      # Use hollow circles
```

But graph is not generated :

[image]

I think the problem is with how I'm creating the data.frame ?

Comment: Try `aes(x=x, y=y)`, i.e. drop the quotes

Comment: added as an answer, since this is SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the quotes in the mapping ("aesthetic") statement aes(), i.e.

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_point(shape=1)      # Use hollow circles
```

(I made this community wiki since it's in Andrie's prior comment)